# Pandas groupby sum multiple columns together

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a London Crime data set that I need to analyse. The below dataframe is a snippet of what the dataframe looks like. I am trying to find the sum of all crimes within each district across the 4 different months of 2018.

```
Crime_type                | Crime sub_type   | District   | 201803 | 201804 | 201805 | 201806 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Arson and Criminal Damage |      Arson      | Westminster |   45   |   90   |    54  |   36   |
Arson and Criminal Damage | Criminal Damage | Westminster |   64   |   35   |    74  |   63   |
Arson and Criminal Damage |      Arson      |   Bexley    |   54   |   19   |    23  |   98   |
Arson and Criminal Damage | Criminal Damage |   Bexley    |   98   |   63   |    89  |   87   |
```

The desired output would be:

```
Westminster: 461
Bexley: 531
```

I know that the Pandas group by function can do what I am trying to achieve but I am unsure how to use it correctly in this instance, finding the sum of mulitple columns. I have it grouping by district and finding the sum within each of the 4 month columns but I wish to find the sum across all 4 columns, not individually.

This is the code I used to achieve the above.

```
df.groupby(['District'])[["201803", "201804", "201805", "201806"]].sum()
```

Comment: Sum it again along the row axis? (what you've got but an additional `.sum(1)` at the end...)

Comment: df.groupby(['District']).sum().sum(axis=1) should be what you are asking for.

Comment: On a side note... an option that might be better (in terms of more flexible) if you've got lots of date columns that are named the same and effectively in ascending order, then you can use: `df.loc[:, '201803':'201806'].sum(1).groupby(df['District']).sum()` to get the same thing... then it's easier to tweak your start/end without explicitly listing every single column

Comment: @JonClements I do have a lot of columns named then same and in ascending order so that is a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution (similar to the comments) would be:

```py
year_months_cols = ["201803", "201804", "201805", "201806"]
df["sum_months"] = df[year_months_cols].sum(axis=1)
df.groupby("District")["sum_months"].agg("sum")
```